# Making shapes in Flash using actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want **to make flowchart to code converter using flash.**
For this, I need to make shapes and then give them required functionality.
**Functionalities in terms of** providing text inside them (for writing statements) and linking arrows with the shapes (Just like in traditional flowchart), so that I can extract statements and come out with code in any language like java,c++,c3 etc.
**Please tell me, How to make shapes in flash builder 4.7 using Action script and provide them functionalities as described above?**
I just started using Flash , so please do not expect that I might knew anything about it.

Comment: Flashbuilder is for code so either you make your graphics/icons outside (ie: Photoshop or get free images) and use code to load/display/position them into your app. You could also try to "draw" the shapes using the [Shape class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html). remember: `Shape` class for code drawing, `Sprite` & `Bitmap` class for loaded images

Comment: Your question is not specific enough.   Consider editing it to include more information about what your "required functionality" is and what your "shapes" are.

Comment: @Batman ,I made it more clear by giving more details.